# fopen() is null when using a string variable as path

Tags: c, fopen

```
char path[strlen(dictionary) + 3];
strcat(path, "./");

// dictionary is "dictionaries/large" char*
strcat(path, dictionary);

// dictionaryFile != NULL
FILE *dictionaryFile = fopen("./dictionaries/large", "r");

// dictionaryFile == NULL
FILE *dictionaryFile = fopen(path, "r");

if (dictionaryFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Not success\n");
}
```

I am trying to open a file inside a folder relative to the current directory of the .c file.

Why is it that when I use the path variable `fopen()` does not work, but when I directly pass the directory it works?

Comment: try `printf("%s", path);` or just `FILE *dictionaryFile = fopen(path, "r"); perror("fopen()")` you will easily see your error.

Comment: `char path[strlen(dictionary) + 3] = "";` will ensure initialization of the string, and let you `strcat` into it.

Comment: You're using `strcat` on an uninitialized buffer, you could have found out yourself by printfing `path`  or by using a debugger.

Comment: @usr That's right, he's using `strlen` there. `strcpy` on the initial copy is better anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char path[strlen(dictionary) + 3];
strcat(path, "./");
```

Here `path` is uninitialized; whereas `strcat` expects it to be null byte terminated. Use `strcpy` instead, for example:

```
char path[strlen(dictionary) + 3];
strcpy(path, "./");
```

However, there may other problems in your code due to which `fopen()` could fail. Check `errno` and use [`perror()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to see why it failed.

Comment: Or just `char path[strlen(dictionary) + 3] = "./";`

Comment: char path[strlen(dictionary) + 3] = "./"; I got this error: variable-sized object may not be initialized. But otherwise, the first solution works.

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot VLAs can't be initialized. So you'll have to use `strcpy` then.